# Reduce multiplicative noise to additive noise with singular matrices

Tags: differentiation, stochastic-processes

I have a stochastic differential equation as

\begin{equation}
   \dot{\textbf{X}}=\textbf{A}\textbf{X}+\alpha(t)\textbf{B}\textbf{X}-\alpha^*(t)\textbf{B}^T\textbf{X}
\end{equation}
where $T$ indicates transpose and the stochastic variable $\alpha$ is a complex-valued Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Physically, I have a set of variables $\textbf{X}$ driven by colored noise.

My plan is to use UCNA method to solve it (http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Papers/79.pdf)

However, in order how it to work, I need to be able to transform my stochastic differential equation with multiplicative noise into a stochastic differential equation with additive noise. And here is where the problem starts:

1. $\textbf{B}$ is singular, so I cannot invert them and isolate the variable $\alpha(t)$.
2. Even if I could invert one of them $\textbf{B}^{-1}$, I would still get $\textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{B}^T$, which it doesn't have to be the identity.

So my questions are: what can be done considering I have singular matrices? Is there a way to solve for both $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{B}^T$?

Comment: Is there relation between $B_1$ and $B_2$? Formulating it differently: is $X$ supposed to be real? If not, you may separate the real and the imaginary parts of the equation, but then you are potentially dealing with the second-order system of equations.

Comment: @RogerV. $B_1$ and $B_2$ are indeed related. Specifically, I found that $B_1=B_2^T$, where $T$ is the transpose. And yes, because the stochastic variable $\alpha$ is complex, then $X$ is in principle complex. However, from numerical simulations, I see that the phase will vanish and at the end of the day, after averaging, X will be real.

Comment: About the second-order system, I am not sure it is that bad. Right now, the difficult part is that I have multiplicative noise (color noise). My goal is first, to get additive noise (color noise) by doing a change of variables, and then use the paper to get again multiplicative noise (white noise). This new noise is much easier to work with.

Comment: There is no general method to convert multiplicative noise to an additive one. There are probably methods applicable to special cases - but here you do not provide enough information about your system. Another useful thing to do would be writing the corresponding Fokker-Planck equation (which would readily give you the stationary distribution.)

Comment: Regarding higher order system: if $X$ were a single variable, the equation would be (formally)  exactly solvable, but with more than one variable and time-dependent coefficients this is generally not the case - so it is potentially much more complex.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot define a F-K equation. The origin of my equation is what's called a Master Equation. In case you are familiar: $\dot{\rho}=\mathcal{L}_{0}\rho+\alpha(t)\mathcal{L}_1\rho-\alpha^*(t)\mathcal{L}_2\rho$, where $\mathcal{L}_{\pm}\rho=\gamma \mathcal{D}[\sigma^\pm]\rho$, where $\sigma$ are the Pauli operators. In physics words, I have a bunch of atoms (two-level systems), driven by color noise.

Comment: I don't think the nature of the equations is important at this point (unless, it hints at making specific approximations - e.g., separating fast and slow dynamics.) I would write the probability function as $W(x_1, x_2, x_3...,t)=\left\langle \prod_i \delta\left(x_i-X_i(t)\right)\right\rangle$, write the equation for it using the Langevin equation given in the OP, and decouple noise (using the fact that it is Gaussian, even in colored.) This is the approach by Kliatskin... (I admit that my background in stochastic systems is somewhat non-canonical by western standards.)

Comment: Just a suggestion: perhaps replace $B_1, B_2\rightarrow B, B^T$ in the OP - it might make it more transparent. Btw, $X$ is a vector or matrix from your point of view? (since you mentioned TLS, there may be misunderstanding of what your equation stands for.)

Comment: Right, I edited the main text. So for $X$ both representations are valid. In general, $X$ is, in my case, a 4x4 matrix, and then $A$ and $B$ are 'superoperators'. On the other hand, one is able to 'vectorize' the matrix by writing it as a column vector, and then $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

Comment: About your Kliatskin comment, do you have any reference were this is applied to any toy (even pedagogical) model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149545/discussion-between-j-agusti-and-roger-v).

Comment: Comment to post (v2): You have replaced $B_1$ and $B_2$ by $B$ and $B^\mathrm{T}$. Your questions are referring to the undefined $B_1$ and $B_2$

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə You are right, my mistake: I edited it and forgot to make the corresponding changes.

Comment: By the way, a suggestion. Can you solve it perurbatively by solving $\dot{\boldsymbol{X}} = \mathbb{A}(t) \boldsymbol{X}$? Its solution is the [ordered exponential](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Ordered_exponential) $\boldsymbol{X}(t) = \mathrm{Texp}\left(\int^t_0 \mathbb{A}(t') \mathrm{d}t'\right)\cdot \boldsymbol{X}(0)$. You can then expand $\mathbb{A}(t)$ into the original $\mathbb{A}$ plus noise and average over the noise.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə how would this time-ordered perturbation be? Is it correct: ${\rm T exp}(\int^t_0 A(t')dt') X(0)\simeq (1+\int^t_0 A(t')dt'+\int^t_0\int^t_0 A(t_1')A(t_2')dt_1'dt_2'+...)X(0) $ and the take the average. Or you mean to take $A(t)=A_0+A_{\rm noise}(t)$?

Comment: I am confused because I haven't worked before with SDEs with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck noise. There is a result that might be of help. In equations with delta-correlated noise and Itô interpretation, sometimes you can obtain additive equations with rotations of the diffusion matrix. You can read a simple explanation and an example in  Gardiner's book on stochastic methods, sections 4.3.5 and 4.4.5 respectively.